# Dygraphs: Collapse/hide part of an x-axis date-range

Tags: javascript, jquery, dygraphs

I have a time-series (x-axis is Date format) which has consistent periods regularly empty, such as evenings and weekends.  I am wondering whether it is possible to automatically collapse/hide a period of time on the x-axis in Dygraphs so that gaps do not appear in my plotted data? (e.g. the x-axis doesn't plot Saturday and Sundays, thus allowing Friday to run directly onto Monday).

Given that I doubt this functionality is available natively, does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this more manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you surmised, there's no support direct for this sort of thing in dygraphs. This has been [discussed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dygraphs-users/implementing%2420time-based%2420charts%2420with%2420gaps%2420in%2420the%2420data%2420for%2420off-hours%2420%28when%2420markets%2420are%2420closed%29%7Csort%3arelevance/dygraphs-users/-lCg5dTGhtA/eQVdBcP5wWIJ) on the mailing in the past.

The gist is that the dygraphs x-axis is always continuous. You'll need to map your time dimension onto something that is continuous, e.g. "market open minutes". Then you'll have to update the tickers and axis/value formatters to reflect this.

It's a fair bit of work but the necessary hooks do all exist. Please do share your solution if you go down this path!

Comment: Sounds reasonable, and I'll let you know if I go down this path and if I do I'll be sure to share.